# rsync sends file to remote daemon server but keeps original ownership and group

Tags: linux, rsync

When running the following command, I hope the ownership and group id (o-and-g) is remained in the remote rsync daemon server. However, every file has the o-and-g the same as configured in `rsync.conf`, [uid] and [gid].

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} rsync_backup@[ipv6]::backupfiles --password-file=/etc/rsyncd.passonly
```

So my question is, how to keep the same o and g instead of using the ones in rsync.conf? Do these users and groups need to be present on that server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rsync` can only change the owner and group to the original when running as root. As you have apparently set a non-root UID in the rsyncd.conf file, `rsync` can only store files as that user. This is a security measure imposed by the operating system, so that ordinary users cannot create files and change the owner to some other user.

Comment: Note that running `rsync` with `sudo` runs it as root on the local computer, but has no effect on the remote computer.

Comment: if a local file has owner Tom, does he has to be present on remote rsync daemon server host?

Comment: @Tiina if you use `--numeric-ids` then only the numeric values of the UID and GID are transferred; normally `rsync -og` will try to preserve the owner and group by name, even if the numeric values are different (e.g. Tom has uid 123 on the source and uid 234 on the destination, then Tom's files will have uid 234 on the destination; with `--numeric-ids` then Tom won't own those files on the destination). If no match can be found for the name, then the numeric value will be used anyway.